# Export Whatsapp Chats

Tags: python, csv, export, chatbot, whatsapp

I'm trying to export a Whatsapp chat to train a model but whatsapp has this policy that only 40k messages can be exported. Is there any way to bypass this limit, so that I can have more data to train?

Comment: [WhatsApp FAQ](https://www.google.com/search?q=export+all+whatsapp+messages+bypass+40k+limit)